# What does the construct companion object : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings) mean?

Tags: kotlin

I am new in Kotlin world and I have a question regarding to `companion object` on the following code snippet:

```
class UserRating(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings)
    var value by UserRatings.value
    var film by StarWarsFilm referencedOn UserRatings.film // use referencedOn for normal references
    var user by User referencedOn UserRatings.user
}
```

I understand the concept of the `companion object` but the code above makes me confuse. What does it mean `companion object : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`companion object` by default has the name `Companion` as a class name.

You can actually define a custom name for this object:

```
companion object MyCompanion
```

Kotlin allows omitting the name **for companion objects** leaving a blank space. A companion object isn't limited and can extend from other classes. The declaration you have means that companion object extends `IntEntityClass` with generic type `UserRating`. Parenthesis after the `IntEntityClass<UserRating>` mean constructor invocation with a single argument. Looks like this single argument is another `object`. It should be defined somewhere as `object UserRatings`.

The syntax is similar to your `UserRating` class declaration.

If we give companion object a name class and companion object declaration start looking much more similar. I'll add an object declaration as well:

```
class UserRating(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id)
companion object MyCompanion : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings)
object JustAnObjectWithoutSuperClass
```

Comment: yes, they are - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: @zero_coding, correct! If you decompile them to Java you will find static final variables that you obviously cannot modify or recreate.

Answer (score 1):

the way I understand it is following:

- there is only one companion object, that you can refer to as `UserRating.Companion`
  alternatively you could express it like this:

```
companion object {
    val property : IntEntityClass<UserRating>(UserRatings)
}
```

and you could refer to it as `UserRating.Companion.property`, the difference is you could have more objects here

- it's type is a [generic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/generics.html) `IntEntityClass<T>`, where `T` is `UserRating`, instantiated with constructor parameter `UserRatings` (in `()` brackets)

Comment: "one companion object" - yes. There can be only one **companion** object per class. "and you could refer to it as `UserRating.Companion.property`, the difference is you could have more objects here" - also true. Picking composition over inheritance is a matter of intention.